# Manipulate a CSV file using Pig

Tags: csv, apache-pig

I tried the following command to load a CSV file using Pig with the command:

`A = LOAD '/USER/XYZ/PIG/FILENAME.ASC' USING PIGSTORAGE(',');`

While it loaded and gave no error, `cat a` gave me a `Directory does not exist error`. I'm new to Pig and know I did something very wrong there. How do I check if it is indeed loaded? Or is loaded a misnomer, and the file just exists on the HDFS?

Next, I'd like to cut a few columns of data from the CSV file and store it in another file. How can I go about it?

I don't necessarily need the script/code, but if you could point me to the right functions that will accomplish what I want to do, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see the current content of `A` you can use [`DUMP`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/test.html#dump)`A;`.  To see the schema/relationship you can use [`DESCRIBE`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/test.html#describe)`A;`.

Once you know the schema of `A` you can project out the fields you want.  E.G. `B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0 AS foo, $4 AS bar ;` to select only the 1st and 5th columns, naming them foo and bar respectively.

Storing can be done with [`STORE`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#store)`B INTO 'myoutdir' USING PigStorage('|') ;` where the char you choose to be a delimiter can be any single char.

So, for example this is how the script would look while I am testing it:

```
A = LOAD '/USER/XYZ/PIG/FILENAME.ASC' USING PIGSTORAGE(',') ;
DESCRIBE A ;
DUMP A ;

B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0, $4;
DESCRIBE B ;
DUMP B ;

STORE B INTO 'myoutdir' USING PigStorage('|') ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the perfect answer! I was away on a vacation and hadn't tested your code out until yesterday. Would you happen to know how to handle multiple files? Like.. If file1, then give columns 2-8, if file2, then give columns 4-6 etc, or is that better achieved through using a script written in Java/Python?

Comment: @CodingInCircles How many files do you have to load? You can always `LOAD` each file individually, then project out the appropriate fields for each alias.

Comment: There are about 100-150 files, maybe more in the future. To maintain that many variables/placeholders, might that not be a challenge?